# Write string to text file and ensure it always overwrites the existing content.

Tags: c#, file, text

I have a string with a C# program that I want to write to a file and always overwrite the existing content.  If the file isn't there, the program should create a new file instead of throwing an exception.

Answer (score 446, accepted):

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText (@"D:\path.txt", contents);
```

- If the file exists, this overwrites it.
- If the file does not exist, this creates it.
- Please make sure you have appropriate privileges to write at the location, otherwise you will get an exception.

Answer (score 37):

Use the [`File.WriteAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx) method. It creates the file if it doesn't exist and overwrites it if it exists.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, `FileMode.Create` is what you're looking for.

Comment: He is asking for an existing file to override

Answer (score 2):

Use the file mode enum to change the `File.Open` behavior. This works for binary content as well as text.

Since `FileMode.Open` and `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` load the existing content to the file stream, if you want to replace the file completely you need to first clear the existing content, if any, before writing to the stream. `FileMode.Truncate` performs this step automatically

```
// OriginalFile:
oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo

// NewFile:
----------------

// Write to file stream with FileMode.Open:
----------------oooooooooooooo
```

```cs
var exists = File.Exists(path);
var fileMode = exists
    ? FileMode.Truncate   // overwrites all of the content of an existing file
    : FileMode.CreateNew  // creates a new file

using (var destinationStream = File.Open(path, fileMode)
{
    await newContentStream.CopyToAsync(destinationStream);
}
```

[FileMode Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filemode?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 0):

If your code doesn't require the file to be truncated first, you can use the FileMode.OpenOrCreate to open the filestream, which will create the file if it doesn't exist or open it if it does.  You can use the stream to point at the front and start overwriting the existing file?

I'm assuming your using a streams here, there are other ways to write a file.