# Non System.Web substitute for HttpPostedFileBase?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, system.web

I am trying to move some `C#` MVC legacy code into a shared DLL. All went well so far, but I was asked that that shared DLL need not reference `System.Web` in any way.

The only type used in that DLL from System.Web is `HttpPostedFileBase`:

```
public string ChangeAttachment(int userId, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    string attachmentsFolderPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AttachmentsDirectory"];
    if (!Directory.Exists(attachmentsFolderPath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(attachmentsFolderPath);
    }

    string fileTarget = Path.Combine(attachmentsFolderPath, userId.ToString() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName));

    if (File.Exists(fileTarget))
    {
        File.Delete(fileTarget);
    }

    file.SaveAs(fileTarget);

    return fileTarget;
}
```

As you can see, no HTTP or Web functionality is needed here, as only its `FileName` and `SaveAs()` members are used.

Is there a substitute that I can easily convert `HttpPostedFileBase` to it at **the caller**, so that all I need to pass as a parameter is a non-web file?

Note: `HttpPostedFileBase` inherits directly from `System.Object`, not from any file class.

Comment: Can't you pass and use FileName to copy the attachment instead of using the SaveAs method?

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz Apparently he can't. Note the `file.SaveAs(fileTarget)` in his source code: He is passing the stream as well.

Comment: @NotSoSharp then he needs to define an interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HttpPostedFileBase` is an abstract class. So the challenge is that you're not actually replacing that class, you're replacing `HttpPostedFileWrapper`, which is the implementation. (It's not what the class inherits from, it's what inherits from it.)

`HttpPostedFileWrapper` in turn references other `System.Web` classes like `HttpInputStream` and 'HttpPostedFile`.

So you can't replace it. Perhaps by asking you not to reference System.Web the intent was that you were moving legacy code not directly related to web functionality, like business logic. If you can't just leave the code out altogether, perhaps you could leave it out of the new assembly you're creating, and then have another assembly which does reference `System.Web`. If they don't need this particular functionality they only reference the one assembly, but if they need this then they can also add the second assembly which does reference `System.Web`.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a FileStream constructor that accepts a derivative of `HttpPostedFileWrapper` as its parameter?

Comment: No. You can look at all of the constructors here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx. (I use the MSDN documentation for classes and methods constantly.)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to Reference `System.Web` and also want to use the [SaveAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase.saveas(v=vs.110).aspx) method, you can define an interface and also a wrapper to make a link. It's not a very simple approach though:

```
//// Second assembly (Without referencing System.Web):
// An interface to link the assemblies without referencing to System.Web
public interface IAttachmentFile {
    void SaveAs(string FileName);
}
..
..
// Define ChangeAttachment method
public string ChangeAttachment(int userId, IAttachmentFile attachmentFile) { 
   string attachmentsFolderPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AttachmentsDirectory"];
   if (!Directory.Exists(attachmentsFolderPath)) {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(attachmentsFolderPath);
   }
   string fileTarget = Path.Combine(
        attachmentsFolderPath, 
        userId.ToString() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName) 
   );
   if (File.Exists(fileTarget)) {
       File.Delete(fileTarget);
   }
   // This call leads to calling HttpPostedFileBase.SaveAs
   attachmentFile.SaveAs(fileTarget);
   return fileTarget;
}

//// First assembly (Referencing System.Web):
// A wrapper class around HttpPostedFileBase to implement IAttachmentFile   
class AttachmentFile : IAttachmentFile {
    private readonly HttpPostedFileBase httpPostedFile;
    public AttachmentFile(HttpPostedFileBase httpPostedFile) {
        if (httpPostedFile == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("httpPostedFile");
        }
        this.httpPostedFile = httpPostedFile;
    }
    // Implement IAttachmentFile interface
    public SaveAs(string fileName) {
        this.httpPostedFile.SaveAs(fileName);
    }
}
..
..
// Create a wrapper around the HttpPostedFileBase object
var attachmentFile = new AttachmentFile(httpPostedFile);

// Call the ChangeAttachment method
userManagerObject.ChangeAttachment(userId, attachmentFile);
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, an interface does not help me here because what I really need is a **converter** from `HttpPostedFileBase`/`HttpPostedFileWrapper` to a binary serializer, similar to the one described [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22417048/5769938) or [this article](http://blog.danskingdom.com/saving-and-loading-a-c-objects-data-to-an-xml-json-or-binary-file/).

Comment: @datps I dont really understand what does your question has to do with binary serializer. You may need to update it for clarification.