# How to save a variables value when leaving the method?

Tags: c#

I have a method which counts the amount of times a user has withdrawn from the atm(as there is a limit) and also counts up the amount of money the user has withdrawn in the day. However the values in the count var and in the `amountWithdrawn` variable are both lost upon leaving the method, how do I keep them "saved"? 
 Also as a side note, I have a class called `Account` which has the balance and such, would it be best to put them there? But would also like to know if it is possible to save the variables in the method for future reference.

```
public decimal WithDraw()
{
    int timesWithdrawn = 9;

    decimal amountWithdrawnToday = 0;
    decimal money = 0;
    bool success = false;
    if (timesWithdrawn < 10)
    {
        do
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("{0} available to withdraw.", FundsAvailable);
            Console.WriteLine("How much would you like to withdraw?");
            try
            {
                money = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                if (money % 5 == 0 && money <= account.CurrentBalance && money <= 1000)
                {
                    success = true;
                }
                if (money == 0)
                {
                    bool exit = true;
                    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to exit? Type \"yes\", or \"no\".");
                    while (exit == true)
                    {
                        string response = Console.ReadLine();
                        if (response.ToLower() == "yes")
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            exit = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number to withdraw.");
            }
        } while (success == false);
        //do while this is true
        Console.WriteLine(account.CurrentBalance);
        Console.WriteLine("Withdrawing {0} pounds.", money);
        Console.WriteLine("You have {0} remaining in your account.", account.CurrentBalance - money);
        amountWithdrawnToday += money;
        timesWithdrawn += 1;
        Console.WriteLine("{0} pounds withdrawn today", amountWithdrawnToday);
        return account.CurrentBalance -= money;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You have exceeded daily withdrawls. You have withdrawn {0}", amountWithdrawnToday);
        return amountWithdrawnToday;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that for this specific use, it'd be better to use the account class, since it hold information about the account. Besides, it is possible to make a "wrapper" class, to return from the method which holds all the information needed outside the method. Another option is using out or ref parameters. sending out parameters changes them in the context they were sent from. You can read more about it here [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/method-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you need to put those variable in the `Account` class, also I suggest that you could put the `withdraw` method itself in the `Account` class, This could be more OOP friendly.

and to save the `timesWithdrawn` number, you just need to make it as *class instance vairable* instead of making it *local variable*

here is the code

```
class Account
{
    public decimal CurrentBalance { get; set; }
    public int timesWithdrawn { get; set; } = 9;

    public decimal WithDraw()
    {
        decimal amountWithdrawnToday = 0;
        decimal money = 0;
        bool success = false;
        if (timesWithdrawn < 10)
        {
            do
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("{0} available to withdraw.", FundsAvailable);
                Console.WriteLine("How much would you like to withdraw?");
                try
                {
                    money = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (money % 5 == 0 && money <= CurrentBalance && money <= 1000)
                    {
                        success = true;
                    }
                    if (money == 0)
                    {
                        bool exit = true;
                        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to exit? Type \"yes\", or \"no\".");
                        while (exit == true)
                        {
                            string response = Console.ReadLine();
                            if (response.ToLower() == "yes")
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                exit = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (FormatException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number to withdraw.");
                }
            } while (success == false);
            //do while this is true
            Console.WriteLine(CurrentBalance);
            Console.WriteLine("Withdrawing {0} pounds.", money);
            Console.WriteLine("You have {0} remaining in your account.", CurrentBalance - money);
            amountWithdrawnToday += money;
            timesWithdrawn += 1;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} pounds withdrawn today", amountWithdrawnToday);
            return CurrentBalance -= money;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have exceeded daily withdrawls. You have withdrawn {0}", amountWithdrawnToday);
            return amountWithdrawnToday;
        }
    }
}
```

as you notice from the code, I removed the reference to the `account` variable and made the `CurrentBalance` as *instance variable* and also the `timesWithdrawn`.

this could preserve the value of the `timesWithdrawn` even after the method has been finished.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the program is running it is saved there, but once quite it resets, so yes you have to save it somewhere in a database a excel table or in a text document 
[Saving data to a file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10337410/saving-data-to-a-file-in-c-sharp)

check this out if you need some help how to do stuff like this

Comment: while you are right, The op not asking about this, The OP asking about getting the value from the method after finish exciting it

Answer (score 0):

You could pass an 'out' parameter to the function, it's basically a variable you send to the function, which holds its value outside the function.
For example:

```
public void WithDraw(out int c) {
    c = something ; //c must receive a value during the call
}  

int myvar; // the parameter which will hold the value when the function returns

WithDraw(out myvar);  //call to the function

myvar  //will now hold a value from the function (something)
```

You could also consider returning a tuple,  or putting the value you wish to save into a 'global variable'.