# Save ListBox items to file

Tags: c#, wpf, file, listbox

I'm trying to create a file, add all the listbox items to the file. SO I can later on open the file and show all the listbox items again.

My current code is not working, it wont create a file or save to a existing file.

Function to get the name of thefile created / path

```
private void mnuFileSaveAs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fileName = "";
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if(fileName == String.Empty)
            {
                mnuFileSaveAs_Click(sender, e);
            }
            else
            {
                fileName = sfd.FileName;
                writeToFile(fileName);
            }

        }

    }
```

Function to write to file

```
private void writeToFile(string fileName)
        {
            System.IO.StreamWriter SaveFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName);
            foreach (var item in listBox.Items)
            {
                SaveFile.WriteLine(item.ToString());
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: and your question is ...?

Comment: Oh I didn't specify it, Well it doesn't work.

Comment: And why duplicate question? What exactly is the question here?

Comment: It doesn't work? Then I think you need to do this and that and make those changes to make it work.

Comment: if you are following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10337410/saving-data-to-a-file-in-c-sharp, which was suggested in your previous question, then you forgot to Close() file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving data to a file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10337410/saving-data-to-a-file-in-c-sharp)

Comment: How is it a duplicate? I'm not following that thread

Comment: What doesn't work? do you see an error? is the file missing data? is the file not created at all?

Comment: Yarimi it says in the question..My current code is not working, it wont create a file or save to a existing file.

Comment: Did you debug the code and check if code is executing properly? Did you notice any unexpected behavior of execution while debugging ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you didn't specify the error, but my guess is that it isn't working because you didn't close the StreamWriter.

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter SaveFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName))
{
    foreach (var item in listBox.Items)
        SaveFile.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

Or you can just call `SaveFile.Close()` instead of `using`